# How to access wget http://XXX from cygwin windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, wget

Following command fails within CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW environment on windows 7 platform, it threw error, even after proper proxy username, password, URL:

> $ wget -c http://ajkpl.kona.pan/tpkn.xes

```
Resolving x.x.x.x (x.x.x.x)... y.y.y.y
Connecting to x.x.x.x (x.x.x.x)|y.y.y.y|:83... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 503 Service Unavailable
2016-03-01 16:07:42 ERROR 503: Service Unavailable.
```

Comment: Can you access the URL using a tool like Curl or PuTTy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Windows is already configured to thru with proxy *and* if cygwin shows http_proxy set to some value, *then* delete http_proxy variable with following command:

`$ unset http_proxy`